# Updating db columns of employees with their joining dates

Tags: php, mysql

We have a table called `emp_details` with the columns `CL` and `PL` which stores employee details with joining dates.

I need to update CL and PL of each employees using the following rule:

difference of (Current date-Date Of Joining) > 10 then CL +=0.5 and PL +=0.5

Could anyone please help me with the query for MySQL

Comment: pleae post your schema

Comment: please define what is this condition `difference of ( DOJ- Current date) > 10`

Comment: Is CL 'compassionate(/unpaid) leave' (as opposed to 'paid leave')? Can that be legitimately quantified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the following structure

```
UPDATE hs_hr_employee AS l
INNER JOIN hs_hr_employee AS r ON l.employee_id = r.employee_id
SET 
    l.CL = (r.cl + 0.5),
    l.PL = (r.pl + 0.5)
WHERE (DATE(NOW()) - DATE(l.joined_date)) > 10
```

Comment: i used teh script but i got error in mysql. here is the errorYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'l.pl = (l.pl + 0.5) WHERE (DATE(NOW()) - DATE(l.joined_date)) > 10' at line 4

Comment: my schema is only an assumption. use your own schema or post the schema so i can make the query according to your schema

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `hs_hr_employee` (
  `emp_number` int(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `employee_id` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `emp_lastname` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `emp_firstname` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `emp_middle_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `joined_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `cl` float NOT NULL,
  `pl` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`emp_number`)  
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'l.PL = (r.pl + 0.5) WHERE (DATE(NOW()) - DATE(l.joined_date)) > 10' at line 5

Comment: i modified the query by adding 'and', now it does nt throw error but it shows 0 row(s) affected.here is my updated query UPDATE hs_hr_employee AS l INNER JOIN hs_hr_employee AS r ON l.employee_id = r.employee_id SET l.CL = ( r.cl + 0.5 ) AND l.PL = ( r.pl + 0.5 ) WHERE (
DATE( NOW( ) ) - DATE( l.joined_date )
) >10

Comment: see your condition as you havent specified what is your criteria

Comment: i need to update cl and pl if difference of curdate and joining date  greater than 10